# if $f(x)=(x-1)/(x+1)$ what is the value, in simplest form of $f \circ f(2015)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$, what is the value, in simplest form, of $f \circ f(2015)$?

Pretty interesting problem. But attempted a lot but couldn't solve it! Would love your guys' help!!

Comment: $\frac{2015-1}{2015+1}=\frac{2014}{2016}=\frac{1007}{1008}$

Comment: Ok i thought there was more to it! Hmm seems not?!

Comment: @janmarqz, It's $f(f(2015))$, not $f(2015)$.

Comment: @BenLongo... yes, it wasn't clear until the re-edit

Comment: Oh sorry, i didnt know how to do it? im still kinda new to this site! Sorry!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general (provided $x \neq 0, -1$),
$$
\begin{align}
f(f(x)) &= f\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)\\
&= \frac{\frac{x-1}{x+1}-1}{\frac{x-1}{x+1}+1}\\
&= \frac{x-1-x-1}{x-1+x+1}\\
&= \frac{-2}{2x}\\
&= \frac 1x
\end{align}
$$
Therefore $f(f(2015)) = \frac1{2015}$.

Comment: And this is easier to see in terms of Möbius transformations: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&-2\\2&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Wow, you know a lot about math sir!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah, right. I knew there was going to be a magical explanation, but I couldn't think of it. Thanks. :)